# MySQL: Subquery WHERE IN (Result from join)

Tags: mysql

My query initializes off of users. From there it grabs all activities done by a user. I get back some data, then i need to also join in sales. I have written a subquery to get the sales results, however, sales does not relate to users, so i need to grab all sales that the account_id is IN that users activities completed.

This query *works* but it is very slow. When I just do s.account_id IN (activity.account_id) it does not bring back the correct numbers.

```
select t.name as team, u.name as "REP NAME", 
  count(distinct (case when activity.tag='visit'  then activity.id 
   end)) as "TOTAL VISITS", 
  count(distinct (case when activity.tag='visit'  then 
   activity.account_id end)) as "UNIQUE VISITS",
  ROUND((select sum(s.volumece) from lpmysqldb.sales s where 
   s.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 

     and s.account_id IN (select 
     account_id from lpmysqldb.activity where 
     org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and user_id=u.id and 
     (completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-04') and 
     tag='visit' and accountname is not null and (status='active' or 
     status='true' or status='1')) 

   and (s.invoice_date between 
   DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01') and DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y- 
   %m-%d'))),2) as "CURRENT YEAR VOLUME"

from lpmysqldb.users u
left join lpmysqldb.teams t on t.team_id=u.team_id
left join lpmysqldb.activity activity on 
 activity.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and activity.user_id=u.id 
 and (activity.completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-04') 
 and activity.accountname is not null and (activity.status IN 
 ('1','active','true','') OR activity.status IS NULL)

where u.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 
 and u.status IN ('active','true','1')
 and istestuser!='1'
group by u.org_id, t.name, u.id, u.name
```

I have spaced out the piece in question for ease of view.
I am not an expert here so any help here would be appreciated!

I believe this is the answer (seems to work much faster)

```
ROUND((select sum(s.volumece) 
from lpmysqldb.sales s 
INNER JOIN  ( select * 
              from lpmysqldb.activity 
              where  org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 
                and (completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04- 
                 04') 
                and tag='visit' 
                and accountname is not null 
                and (status='active' or status='true' or status='1')) 
             T on T.account_id = s.account_id
where s.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852'
  and T.user_id=u.id
  and (s.invoice_date between DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01') and 
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d'))
    ),2) as "CURRENT YEAR VOLUME",
```

Comment: MySQL often does poorly with `WHERE col in (SELECT ...)`. Change it to an `INNER JOIN` and it usually does better.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the insight. However, I am getting an error on using the initial table user_id=u.id

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question. You're allowed to answer your own question if you discovered the solution yourself.

Comment: Incidentally, I like `status IN('active','true',1);` - although it's alarming that status can be all of these things

Comment: By products of moving data around

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid then IN clause simply using an inner join  eg:

```
  select t.name as team, u.name as "REP NAME", 
    count(distinct (case when activity.tag='visit'  then activity.id 
     end)) as "TOTAL VISITS", 
    count(distinct (case when activity.tag='visit'  then 
     activity.account_id end)) as "UNIQUE VISITS",
    ROUND(( 
    select sum(s.volumece) 
    from lpmysqldb.sales s 
    INNER JOIN (select 
       account_id from lpmysqldb.activity where 
       org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and user_id=u.id and 
       (completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-04') and 
       tag='visit' and accountname is not null and (status='active' or 
       status='true' or status='1')) T on T.account_id = s.account_id
     where  s.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 
     and (s.invoice_date between 
     DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01') and DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y- 
     %m-%d'))),2) as "CURRENT YEAR VOLUME"
  from lpmysqldb.users u
  left join lpmysqldb.teams t on t.team_id=u.team_id
  left join lpmysqldb.activity activity on 
   activity.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and activity.user_id=u.id 
   and (activity.completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-04') 
   and activity.accountname is not null and (activity.status IN 
   ('1','active','true','') OR activity.status IS NULL)

  where u.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 
   and u.status IN ('active','true','1')
   and istestuser!='1'
  group by u.org_id, t.name, u.id, u.name
```

Comment: thanks for the insight. However, I am getting an error on using the initial table user_id=u.id in that join

Comment: ansyway answer  updated  ..hope with the correcy nesting

Comment: there error was Unknown column 'u.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: I think i have it.. thank you for the assistance

**editied my question